# android gradle com.android.support libraries version issue

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

When i build my gradle, i got a error. Hint shows:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.0.2, 25.3.1 Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2 and com.android.support:design:25.3.1

This is my gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(':rest')
// Google
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'


// Analytics
// Fabric + Crashlytics
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

// Facebook
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
// Tools
// App Intro
compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
// FloatingActionButton menu
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.1'
// Animation items for RecyclerView
compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.0.1'
// Photo banner
compile 'com.bigkoo:convenientbanner:2.0.5'
// Time picker support for 4.0+
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.5.0'
// Displays the relative time with respect to the reference point
compile 'com.github.curioustechizen.android-ago:library:1.3.0'
compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.0'
// Image loader (for high resolution pics)
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
// Icon font
compile "com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.8.1@aar"
compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.3.original@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz:material-design-iconic-typeface:2.2.0.2@aar'
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'

compile 'com.tomergoldst.android:tooltips:1.0.6'
}
```

I also follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)
Change

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
```

However, after i sync my project. The hint shows:

```
This support library should not use a different version(27) than the compileSdkVersion(25)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification/42589182

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Comment: I tried the answer, but still error. Change to sdk 27 is better way, I thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use the latest version for your support libs (27.1.1). Also change from compile to implementation, compile has been deprecated. Finally, change your compileSdkVersion to 27 in your app level build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(':rest')
// Google
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'


// Analytics
// Fabric + Crashlytics
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

// Facebook
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
// Tools
// App Intro
implementation 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
// FloatingActionButton menu
implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.1'
// Animation items for RecyclerView
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.0.1'
// Photo banner
implementation 'com.bigkoo:convenientbanner:2.0.5'
// Time picker support for 4.0+
implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.5.0'
// Displays the relative time with respect to the reference point
implementation 'com.github.curioustechizen.android-ago:library:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.0'
// Image loader (for high resolution pics)
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
// Icon font
implementation "com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.8.1@aar"
implementation 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.3.original@aar'
implementation 'com.mikepenz:material-design-iconic-typeface:2.2.0.2@aar'
implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'

implementation 'com.tomergoldst.android:tooltips:1.0.6'
}
```

Comment: Thank! After change to sdk 27 and add  `implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1"`
no error appeared.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, in my case was related to the facebook sdk version use 4.33.0 instead of 4.+ and update your support librareis to version 27.0.2